# How to mininimize power consumption for a blue tooth remote

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, hardware

I am creating a remote that will send out constant signals over blue tooth.  I need to have the signals be sent out with the smallest amount of power consumption possible.  What would be the way to send out blue tooth signals with the lowest possible power consumption?   I am thinking that I will use an arduino to write some c++ that can run barebones  (no operating system).  Someone recommended to me that I should write the device in arm assembly, but I don't know how I would go about doing that and am unsure if the performance gain will be that great or worth it.  What are some other option?

Answer (score 0):

We ended up using [this micro controller](http://redbearlab.com/blenano/)